# Dynamic ID generation

Tags: jquery, aem

In AEM, I added a dropdown component with the same id, so I did like dynamic id using JQuery, but last incremented value is assigned to all of the ids.

```
var count=0;

$(".tab").each(function(count) { 
    $("select.tab-select").attr("id","tab-select"+count);

    count++;
});
```

Comment: Use `let count=0;` instead. Also your function does not take any parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this` keyword like:

```
$(".tab").each(function(index) {
    $("select.tab-select", this).attr("id","tab-select"+index);
});
```

**NOTE:** You don't need to increment a count variable since the `each()` function already return incremented value as the index.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `each()` loop here. You can instead provide a function to `prop()` which accepts the index of the current element, then returns the new value to be set, like this:

```
$("select.tab-select").prop("id", function(i) {
  return 'tab-select' + i;
});
```